# Is it possible to animate an UIImage?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5, uiimage

I'm wondering if there's anyway to animate an `UIImage`.

I know that `UIImageViews` are possible to animate but is there any way to do it directly in a `UIImage`.

Maybe with Open GL ES or something?

Or are there any other ways you can animate an `MPMediaItemArtwork`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What kind of animation are you looking for? Simple translation and movement? or changing displays?

Comment: Changing between multiple frames basically, kind of like a .gif. Like first show image1 then image2 then image3 etc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Create a `UIImageView` and set the property of `animationImages` to an array of `UIImage`s

Here is an example:

```
NSArray *animationFrames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
  [UIImage imageWithName:@"image1.png"],
  [UIImage imageWithName:@"image2.png"], 
  nil];

UIImageView *animatedImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
animatedImageView.animationImages = animationsFrame;
[animatedImageView startAnimating];
```

If you're targeting iOS 5 you can do this directly in `UIImage` without the `UIImageView` using

```
    +(UIImage *)animatedImageWithImages:(NSArray *)images duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

for example,

```
    [UIImage animatedImagesWithImages:animationFrames duration:10];
```

Answer (score 8):

If you mean animation with a few images, use this code:

```
   // create the view that will execute our animation
 UIImageView* YourImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];

 // load all the frames of our animation
 YourImageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:    
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"01.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"02.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"03.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"04.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"05.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"06.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"07.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"08.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"09.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"10.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"11.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"12.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"13.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"14.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"15.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"16.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"17.gif"], nil];

 // all frames will execute in 1.75 seconds
 YourImageView.animationDuration = 1.75;
 // repeat the animation forever
 YourImageView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
 // start animating
 [YourImageView startAnimating];
 // add the animation view to the main window 
 [self.view addSubview:YourImageView];
```

[Source](http://appsamuck.com/day2.html)

Answer (score 1):

Check UIImage's `+animatedImageWithImages:duration:` and `+animatedImageNamed:duration:`.

From [UIImage Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/animatedImageWithImages:duration:):

> Creates and returns an animated image from an existing set of images.
>
> This method loads a series of files by appending a series of numbers to the base file name provided in the name parameter. For example, if the name parameter had ‘image’ as its contents, this method would attempt to load images from files with the names ‘image0’, ‘image1’ and so on all the way up to ‘image1024’. All images included in the animated image should share the same size and scale.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
arrayOfImages=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for(int i=1;i<=54;i++)
{
NSString *nameResources=@"haKsequence.png";
NSString *changedString= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i];
NSString *stringWithoutSpaces = [nameResources     stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"K" withString:changedString];
[arrayOfImages addObject:(id)[UIImage imageNamed:stringWithoutSpaces].CGImage];
}


self.view.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
i1.hidden=YES;
image1=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
image1.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
image1.frame = button.frame;//i1 is obshaped buttion
[self.view addSubview:image1];
CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"contents"];
animation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationDiscrete;
animation.duration = 1;
animation.values   = arrayOfMonkeyImages;
[animation setDelegate:self];
animation.repeatCount=3;
[animation setRemovedOnCompletion:YES];
[image1.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"animation"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4 version:

```
let animationImages = [UIImage(named: "image1.png"), UIImage(named: "image2.png")]
imageView.animationImages = animationImages
imageView.animationDuration = 10
imageView.startAnimating()
```