# How to shuffle Between Images In UIImageView

Tags: iphone

I'm making a game where the player throws a cube. I have 6 images that correspond to each cube, and I want to have shuffle effect like it's randomly choosing between 1-6. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this post: [Is it possible to animate an UIImage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545154/is-it-possible-to-animate-an-uiimage)

All you need to do is stop the animation when you have selected the random image.

As @kernix said in the comment, to stop the animation after it has animated once, all you need to do is set the repeat count to 1.

```
imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1
```

In order to have a callback method called after the animation, please see the following post: [Access Method After UIImageView Animation Finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9283270/access-method-after-uiimageview-animation-finish)

Comment: I want it to stop animating when it gets the the last image in the array, is that possible? Yep need to set imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1;

Comment: is it possible to have a callback when the animation ended?

Comment: thanks, I ended up implemeting the animation myself using NSTimer.