# Programmatically create UIImage animation with frames

Tags: ios, uiimage, swift2, xcode7, watchos-2

I am generating a bunch of frames which I want to animate on my Apple Watch.

According to info I've found on the internet, everyone seems to be using `imageWithName` to animate a `UIImage`, such as the following SO post: [Is it possible to animate an UIImage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545154/is-it-possible-to-animate-an-uiimage)

The first answer suggest the following code which uses `UIImageView`:

```
NSArray *animationFrames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
  [UIImage imageWithName:@"image1.png"],
  [UIImage imageWithName:@"image2.png"], 
  nil];

UIImageView *animatedImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
animatedImageView.animationImages = animationsFrame;
[animatedImageView startAnimating];
```

However `UIImageView does not seem to exist in XCode 7 with Swift when I try to add it to my Apple Watch code? ***Why?***

---

**I also try the following code which I wrote myself:**

```
...

var frames = [UIImage]()
var animation = UIImage()

...

//1. generate frame
//2. add to array "frames"

animation.images = frames //apply frame array to main animatable UIImage.
```

The last line gives me an error which says:

> Cannot assign to property: 'images'is a get-only property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
    UIImage.animatedImageWithImages(images: [UIImage], duration: NSTimeInterval)
```

To create your animating `UIImage`

i.e.

```
var animation = UIImage.animatedImageWithImages(images: frames, duration: NSTimeInterval)
```